# Сборка Angular 4 приложения

Tags: angular4

Добрый день. Возможно ли собрать Angular 4 приложение, чтобы его можно было запускать без какого либо сервера и хостинга, а просто HTML файл на локальной машине?

Comment: Что Вы подразумеваете под "запуском на локальной машине"?

Comment: Без хостинга, и без использования какого либо сервера. Чтобы люди, которые не разбираются в программировании просто могли запустить HTML файл

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то после [сборки приложения](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build) появляется папка dist и в ней лежат js и html которые можно просто запустить. Правда возможно пути подключения js в html кривые